# Render tag label only if there are tags

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I want to render the “Tags:” label only if the post has actual tags. When I write

```
{{post.tags | size}}
```

I get the number of tags. However, if I put it in an `{% if %}` condition:

```
{% if post.tags | size != '0' %}
```

it always yields true. I worked around this problem with

```
{% capture tagsize %}{{post.tags | size}}{% endcapture %}
{% if tagsize != '0' %}
```

but it seems very ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

**Note**: I use GitHub Pages, so using a plugin – other than being an overkill – is not an option. My Jekyll version is `2.0.4` as specified [here](https://pages.github.com/versions/) as of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `{{ post.tags }} == empty array`.

As we cannot do `{% if post.tags != [] %}`, we just add `array: []` in `_config.yml`.

We can now do :

```
{% if post.tags != site.array %}
  Do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sounds kind of hacky, but if there is no other way…

Answer (score 0):

tag size returns an integer and not a string so you should compare against 0 and not '0'

```
{% if page.tags.size != 0 %}
  <!-- some code to render tags --> 
{% endif %}
```